# How Can I Center My Forms Button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm using a Cognito Form and it works well, the only thing that irritates me is that the "submit" button won't center. I've tried , that simply made the text boxes above it centered, while the submit button was still on the left hand side. I don't see very many other options for this.
https://gyazo.com/bd4a143cefe2a0f764a82bd922f92e6f

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/kQtsv-uYpE2Bbu47xu3lPw">    </script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "1" });</script></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Give its parent `text-align: center`

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* If that script is generating the HTML & CSS, the result of the script is what needs to be in your question. We can't troubleshoot this from the script tags.

Comment: All I have is a script tag. The form is hosted on Cognito Forms. I was simply given that script to paste into my code. See my problem now?

Comment: No, as the rendered html still will be there and follow css rules you add in addition to the built in one's. Right click the button, chose "Inspect", find its parent class name and add the `text-align: center` to it

Comment: I tried that, and it does move the button but it takes the entire form with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below script just before end of span tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector(".cognito .c-action").style="text-align: center;float:none;";
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: This took a little tweaking of my Cognito form, but the script worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still looking for the answer to this. Using seamless embed and the following css worked for me:

```
.cognito .c-action{
    float:none !important;
}
.c-action #c-submit-button, .c-action{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to CSS but I remember having an exact problem. Try this create a CSS file
and add a element let's say center-button and then apply the text-aligh:center

Example

```
.center-button{
  text-align:center!important;
}
```

On html page

```
<div class="cognito center-button">
```

If that fails you might want to play around with margins.

```
 .center-button{
    margin-left: 50%;
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. Why is this simple button so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 using seamless embed this CSS worked for me:

```
.cog-page__navigation {
  justify-content: center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: center;`

worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.